# Tokenizing any model instance in django (DRF)

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework, token

So i am working with Django and `django-rest-knox` for token based authentication. It works fine but what i want now is to tokenize any other model instance instead of a user instance.

Normal way;

```
from knox.models import AuthToken

AuthToken.objects.create(user=myuser)
```

What i tried;

```
AuthToken.objects.create(some_other_model_instace)
```

Which gives an error;

```
AuthToken.user" must be a "User" instance
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Define a serializer for your custom user model and then bind it to Knox settings. It should TL the trick, see https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/settings/

Comment: Can you please show how to do that, as it is still showing the error. Also in my custom model, i have username, image and contact field. There is no password as i am building a passwordless app